Android Fragments - Return back to same fragment after switching back to initial tab
I am trying to understand the architecture which is being followed by most of the android app nowadays. (example: YouTube, Whatsapp etc)
Lets say we have two tabs Tab1 and Tab2
And we have three fragments inside Tab1, two fragments inside tab2
Flow is something like this

Tab1 -> frag1(base fragment)->frag2->frag3
Tab2 -> frag4(base fragment)->frag5->frag6

On Tab1, we go to frag1, then frag2, then frag3 and then switch to Tab2.
If we again go back to Tab1, we should return to frag3 (Which is there in most of the apps nowadays)
Please help me with approach.
As far as I know, using addtobackstack() only serves as solution for pressing backbutton.
